# Managed File Portal

Tags: ftp, liferay, portal

We would like a portal where we can put up file assets and then control access to them (or sets of them) on a per customer login basis.

Open source/Free where by we could self host would be ideal.

Any suggestions will be really appreciated!

Comment: Anyone had any experience using solutions such as: http://www.hyperoffice.com/customer-portal/ ?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Alfresco (Share). There's a community edition as well.